# Class Library shared between an UWP app and a Bot Framework chatbot

Tags: .net, uwp, .net-core, botframework, class-library

I want to create a Class Library .dll that I want to include in my UWP app and my Bot Framework chatbot, that includes newtonsoft json dependencies. From what I can see this is just not possible. If I create it with .NetFramework and the bot reference it fine but the UWP app shows an error:

[image]

If I create it as a Class Library of type .NET Core, I can reference it in both projects, but there is a problem with the newtonsoft dependencies inside the library.
I don't want to start digging into this NuGet creation process, because it brings me no benefit at this point. I want to use dll.

Is it even possible to create a shared lib? I cannot believe it's that stupid

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275760/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-shared-libraries-available-to-multiple-applications

and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3707x96z(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

According to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library

if you want to target UWP apps, your .NET Core dll must be on `.NET Standard 1.4` or less.

Just edit your `.csproj` file and change the `NetStandard` target framework :

`<TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>`

EDIT: Also check the "Which .NET Standard version to target" section for best practices about using .NET Standard.